WP Mail SMTP Plugin Fails Certificate Verification
I am using WordPress v6.7 with the WP Mail SMTP plugin v4.20 on a Windows 10 v23H2 development computer.  The WP Mail SMTP fails to send a test message using WP Mail SMTP's test email function.  I get the following error message:
OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed SMTP server error: QUIT command failed

My installation of OpenSSL is v1.1.1.g.  It is configured to use the Windows 10 Certificate Store.  I've spent the last 8 days trying to figure out the problem.  I've temporarily disabled Norton 360 and Malwarebytes but the failure continued.  I've replaced my SSD thinking this might be the issue but it's not.
Anybody know why this might be happening?

The issue turned out to be the Norton 360 antivirus program I am running!  It seems Norton recently changed the behavior of their right-click "Disable Auto-Protect" (11/2024).  In the past, when this option was selected, every function associated with Auto-Protect would be disabled, including email scanning.  That's not the case any longer.  Now, when this option is selected, Auto-Protect disables protection for file scanning but not for email scanning.  Disabling email scanning is found in another Norton 360 setting at Settings>Antivirus>Email Protection.  The setting that causes WP Mail SMTP to fail certificate verification is the "Scan outbound mails (SMTP)".  Disabling this setting will stop the WP Mail SMTP certificate verification failure.
It would have been nice for Norton to notify its customers or provide a Help icon to let them know that the behavior of "Disable Auto-Protect" has changed, but they didn't.

thank you for coming back here and for explaining how you solved this but this problem is more on the server side then it's not the good place here on WordPress Development Stack Exchange. I think this issue may rather be on his place on https://serverfault.com.
